# How to safely get two mutable pointers to same int?

Tags: rust, unsafe-pointers

I would like to create a Rust semaphore wrapping the libc `sem_post` and `sem_wait` functions, both of which take a mutable `int *` parameter. This requires that the waiter and poster simultaneously have a mutable pointer to the same int. How can I arrange this without risking UB?

One thought I had was to use `UnsafeCell`:

```rust
use libc;
use std::cell::UnsafeCell;

pub struct Sema {
    sema: UnsafeCell<i32>,
}

impl Sema {
    pub fn post(&self) {
        unsafe { libc::sem_post(self.sema.get()) };
    }

    pub fn wait(&self) {
        unsafe { libc::sem_wait(self.sema.get()) };
    }
}
```

Is this safe, and is there a better way? Thanks for any help!

Comment: Note that you should use `UnsafeCell<libc::sem_t>`, otherwise your code is unsound on 64-bit systems.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Raw pointers*, the `*mut T` or `*const T` types, have no aliasing requirements or other validity constraints. It is always safe to create a pointer; note that `UnsafeCell::get()` is not an `unsafe fn`.

And in this case, by using `UnsafeCell` you've also ensured that Rust has no expectations that would be violated by *using* the pointer with `libc`. (This would not be the case if you had `sema: i32`, for example.)

I'm not going to say that your semaphore code is sound or correct, because I'm not familiar with these functions, but I feel confident saying it isn't *misusing Rust pointer types.*